# Equals operator returns false in for of loop? ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't seem to understand why my code returns false. I tried googling for answers but found nothing.

```
let board = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]];
for (row of board) {
    console.log(row == [1, 1, 1]) 
}
```

Even though every "row" is [1,1,1] it logs false. Why is this?

Comment: Arrays are not compared the way your code expects them to be. Two different arrays will never be `==` to each other.

Comment: You should compare element by element